# How to Split A Value by Delimiter Into Different Rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

I'm a newbie and have had a problem that I searched these forums and found that I needed to have UDF defined function to split a value because SQL Server does not have a built-in function to split a value based on a delimiter. Based on an article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str), I was able to implement the following but it's not working well from a performance perspective. I have about 75000 records and it's taking a long time to run.

*The end result is that I need to take all the purchase values (delimitted by |) and put each value with the name into a table. I may at times have 4 values separated by the | or 3,2 none.*

Can someone provide some pointers or a different solution? Maybe do this split using a solution like AutoIT off-line? Or in SSIS?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and SSIS to load the data.

Help!

Thanks

Dave

```
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Staging_Table TABLE
(
 ACCTID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
 NAME VARCHAR(50),
 PURCHASES VARCHAR(255)
 )

INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (Name, Purchases)
VALUES ('John','Vanilla|Chocolate|Peach')

INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (Name, Purchases)
VALUES ('Jack','Chocolate|Vanilla')

INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (Name, Purchases)
VALUES ('Mary','Peach|Vanilla|Bean')

INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (Name, Purchases)
VALUES ('Peter','Vanilla|Peach')

INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (Name, Purchases)
VALUES ('Jane','Bean|Vanilla|Chocolate|Peach')

-- Get the number of rows in the looping table
 DECLARE @RowCount INT
 SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ACCTID) FROM @Staging_Table)



-- Declare an iterator
DECLARE @I INT
-- Initialize the iterator
 SET @I = 1


-- Loop through the rows of a table @myTable
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold the data which we get after looping each record

     DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(255), @PURCHASES VARCHAR(255)  

     -- Get the data from table and set to variables
     SELECT 
        @NAME = NAME, 
        @PURCHASES = PURCHASES
    FROM 
        @Staging_Table
    WHERE 
        ACCTID = @I

    -- Display the looped data
        SELECT 
            @I,
            @NAME,  
            t.txt_value
            FROM dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(@PURCHASES, '|') as t 

            SET @I = @I  + 1
     END



END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        DECLARE @Tally TABLE (N INT)
        DECLARE @i AS INT = 1
        WHILE @i != 1000
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Tally (N)  VALUES (@i)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
        --------------------------------------------------------
        DECLARE @Staging_Table TABLE 
                    (ACCTID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                    ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
                    ,PURCHASES VARCHAR(255))
        INSERT INTO @Staging_Table (NAME,Purchases)
        VALUES ('John','Vanilla|Chocolate|Peach')
              ,('Jack','Chocolate|Vanilla')
              ,('Mary','Peach|Vanilla|Bean')
              ,('Peter','Vanilla|Peach')
              ,('Jane','Bean|Vanilla|Chocolate|Peach')
              ,('Jane','Bean Vanilla Chocolate Peach')

    ----------------------------------------------------------
    --1 variant:

        SELECT E.NAME,f3.Purch
        FROM @Staging_Table AS E
        INNER JOIN @Tally AS T ON SUBSTRING('|' + E.Purchases, T.N, 1) = '|' AND T.N < LEN(E.Purchases) + 1
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT string = SUBSTRING(' ' + E.Purchases + '|', T.N + 1, LEN(E.Purchases) + 1)) f1
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT p1 = CHARINDEX('|', string)) f2
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Purch = SUBSTRING(E.Purchases, T.N, p1-1)) f3
        ORDER BY E.NAME
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    --2 variant:

        SELECT  E.NAME ,
        ( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', S.string) > 0
               THEN LEFT(S.string, CHARINDEX('|', S.string) - 1)
               ELSE string
          END ) AS Purch
        FROM    @Staging_Table AS E
        INNER JOIN @Tally AS T ON SUBSTRING('|' + PURCHASES, T.N, 1) = '|'
                                  AND T.N <= LEN(PURCHASES)
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    String = ( CASE WHEN T.N = 1
                                                THEN ( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',
                                                              E.PURCHASES) > 0
                                                            THEN LEFT(E.PURCHASES,
                                                              CHARINDEX('|',
                                                              E.PURCHASES) - 1)
                                                            ELSE E.PURCHASES
                                                       END )
                                                ELSE SUBSTRING(E.PURCHASES,
                                                              T.N, 1000)
                                           END )
                    ) S
        ORDER BY E.NAME
```

Comment: This suggestion worked really well. It was faster than what I had plus it did the job exactly to what I needed. I liked your ideas and definitely something that I need to learn!

Comment: @Dave, one comment, better to keep Tally Table with indexes, will be more faster than now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but being a newbie, I'm a little unsure of what to do. I think I must reaching some bad data or a scenario that is causing an issue but I'm getting an error as Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 66 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I think the issue is that some of my data doesn't have a |. That's where it's blowing up. 

How do I include that as scenario?

Comment: @Dave 2 variant has been updated, in case when '|' not exist then you will retrieve full string (not split)

Comment: Thank you once again! You have been a big help. I need to send you an XMAS gift :)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to store data like this, but I will tell you a solution I have found that works. Ideally, you would do this outside of the SQL server. This works fast enough for me.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempValues (
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    val VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Create a temporary table to hold the data. The solution is a recursive function takes the left hand side, and then recalls the functions on the right hand side.

```
CREATE FUNCTION breakStringUp
    @nameTemp VARCHAR(100),
    @stringToSplit VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
     IF FIND(@stringToSplit, '|') > 0
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempValues
        ( name, val)
        VALUES
        (@nameTemp, LEFT(@stringToSplit,
                             FIND(@stringToSplit, '|'));

         breakStringUp(@nameTemp,
                 RIGHT( /* Recurse into the function, The index is 
                                                 taken from the right side so invert it
                                                 LEN(@stringToSpit)-FIND(...) */)
                )
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #tempValues ..............
      END
```

The above code is a little complicated. I just wrote the pseudocode, but it should work depending on the schema.

```
  DECLARE CURSOR FOR ........
```

Declare a cursor over the row and iterate. Call the function on each name and corresponding VARCHAR.

```
  SELECT * FROM #tempValues;
```

And clean up the temporary table

```
DROP #tempValues;
```

Comment: Hi @LeBarton - thanks for replying back, but since I'm a newbie I'm going to have to do more to figure it out how to implement your suggestion because I'm still not sure about how to use cursors, also in my research, it states that cursors are slow?

Comment: Cursors are slower than the standard sql statements (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT). Unfortunately, your data schema is not standard SQL, so you can't use standard SQL methods to work on it. Instead of storing the data in a single row, the data should be stored in multiple rows. I ran into your exact same problem where I had to use T-SQL to solve it, and the above is the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is slow with string manipulation, so any SQL implementation will be horrible, performance-wise. If you are truly into the speed, you will have to create a CLR function - being properly written, it will beat any SQL on this particular task, hands down.

Another option, which might or might not be a viable solution in your case, is SSIS package.

Meanwhile, you can try to use XML for row splitting - it might be even worse than loops, though (not to mention many other deficiencies):

```
select t.ACCTID, t.NAME, p.c.value('./@v', 'varchar(50)') as [PurchaseItem]
from @Staging_Table t
    cross apply (
        select cast('<r><i v="'
            + replace(t.PURCHASES, '|', '"/><i v="')
            + '" /></r>' as xml
        ) as [XData]
    ) ca
    cross apply ca.XData.nodes('/r[1]/i') p(c);
```

Comment: Thanks @Roger-wolf, can you recommend any resources on learning how to create a CLR function specific to what I need done?

You mentioned SSIS package, did you mean create a script to perform the manipulation using LEN, FIND and LEFT? I thought about that but quickly lost any idea on how to do a for loop since I'll have to find out the number of occurrences for the | character.

Appreciate your time and suggestion!

Comment: SSIS would be good for data resided in file; if it's already in some table, better to forget it. As for the examples of CLR string splitting - there are in abundance everywhere. Just as an example: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx